# How to create walletconflicts in regtest mode?

Tags: bitcoind, json-rpc, transaction-malleability, regtest

I play with Bitcoin Core 0.13 in regtest mode using python. Now I use [bitcoin-testnet-box](https://github.com/freewil/bitcoin-testnet-box), I have two nodes connected to each other. I want to create a walletconflict. I want to get `gettransaction <txid>` result with non-empty `walletconflicts` field.

**How can I achiev this?**

I've tried to get two different addresses from one node and send money to them from another, using raw transactions api and `-zapwallettxes` restart, but the second txid is not visible in the recipient wallet.

Comment: Guys, any suggestions?